# How to fill correctly HTML canvas with lines and arcs?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to create figure consist of lines and curves like below.
And I also want to fill it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

// half of arc
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI);

ctx.moveTo(100, 125);
ctx.lineTo(10, 125);  // bottom line
ctx.lineTo(10, 25);   // left line
ctx.lineTo(100, 25);  // left line
ctx.stroke();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

However `ctx.fill()` discards curve and fill in rectangular form like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#

      // half of arc
      ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI);

    ctx.moveTo(100, 125);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 125); // bottom line
    ctx.lineTo(10, 25); // left line
    ctx.lineTo(100, 25); // left line
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I fill my figure correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw your lines in a logic order.

```js
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 125)
    ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 25); // left line
    ctx.lineTo(10, 125); // bottom line
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Alternatively you can do it like this:

```js
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 1.5 * Math.PI, .5 * Math.PI,true);
    ctx.moveTo(100, 125);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 125); // bottom line
    ctx.lineTo(10, 25); // left line
    ctx.lineTo(100, 25); // left line
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```